# How to hide custom shapes' object for bones in armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, layers

I'm using custom shapes for a character armature. These shapes are objects that are floating around in my 3D space. They aren't really connected to the armature or the character mesh.

However, when I append the character mesh to a project, all these custom shapes follow along, as objects. This clutters up my 3D view, and I have to remove these objects every time I append a character mesh.

Is there any way of hiding these/putting them into the armature layer/not appending them somehow when I'm appending a character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlink these objects from the scene:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(bpy.context.active_object)
```

Pros:

- There will be no clutter, even no extra stuff in outliner
- You will be able to still see them in the dataview outliner.
- Bones will still use them as shapes
- They won't be deleted with file save
- It will still work with file linking

Cons:

- You will have to link them back to scene to make changes, so do this last
- Other people won't know what's going on, it's not standard and I would do this only on personal projects
- It might not work with future blender releases, its a hack.

Comment: Are there other ways of doing this?  Surely it is not necessary for Blender to append these items!

Comment: Nowadays I make a collection Bone Shapes, make sure it's next to the one that is for linking the character(not inside it) and I put all the bone widgets there. When I disable that collection with its checkmark all is tidy and linking and overriding works as expected too.